# AWS lambda function Increase speed by parallel run

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

my code steps are connect to api, extract data from api and store it in database, this is done in loop doing some task over and over again, I'm trying to see how can I increase my speed, my goal is to run all of them at once instead of having one running after the other ... Can I do my loop in parallel way or not ? can someone show me an example of the best way to solve my issue ? or have experience with loops and parallel aws lambda function ? thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You could change your code to only insert the data into **DynamoDB** at the *end* of the function, not for every individual item. This would use the [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) API call, which should reduce the time required for each execution of the function.

Or, you could change the design to allow **parallel use of AWS Lambda**:

- Push messages into an **Amazon SQS queue** with a few ticker symbols per message
- Subscribe the **AWS Lambda function** to the SQS queue
- When invoked, the Lambda function will be passed the contents of the message from SQS, and it can process the ticker symbols listed in the message

This will run multiple Lambda functions in parallel. The default limit is **1000 concurrent Lambda functions** but you can request an increase to this limit.

Comment: I never used SQS, can we push all the tickers symbols at once instead to have to do it one by one ?

Comment: The idea is to push each of the ticker symbols into separate messages, or perhaps a group of ticker symbols per message (eg 10 per message). That way, each Lambda function is working on a small chunk of the problem and they can run in parallel. You will need to write a small script to push those messages into SQS (just a few lines of code). However, while testing the system, just push one message or a few messages to confirm it is working okay.